# Why do android studio show the following warnings while importing?

Tags: android, android-studio

The following imports are in yellow but no error is thrown, clicking on them takes me to respective class of support-annotations jar as well:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull; 
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
```

[image]

Message on hover:

[image]

How can I mark code inside android.support.annotation as depricated, it is not my code.

Comment: no error is there on pointing cursor. everything works fine in the app, just that the colour looks fishy.

Comment: You mean yellow?

Comment: Are you sure that you hovered the mouse pointer over those imports?  Android Studio really says nothing?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 let me check in my system

Comment: I think it's yellow let me update my question, sorry I am bit color blind

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: my bad, updated the question.

Comment: So far i know, all the annotation imports are shown in yellow color..it's normal, there won't be any issue

Comment: Looks OK to me...anyway if your app builds and deploys, and you can `CTRL` + click into those annotation classes, then functionally everything is working.

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar I realized that too, just curious if there is way to get rid of those warnings other than annotating it inside annotations package as depicated.

Comment: You could change your API build level to something earlier...but that might not be desirable and could break other things.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Yellow lines for these imported class signifies annotation  class , it is by default yellow in color , therefore there is nothing wrong in your coding .

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;